# Django Crispy Forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am fairly new to Django and I have installed and am trying to use crispy forms in my web app.I have added crispy_forms to my installed apps with a comma after it. When I run the server I get this error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\backends\django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "C:\Users\amart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\amart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_field.py", line 10, in <module>
    from crispy_forms.utils import TEMPLATE_PACK, get_template_pack
  File "C:\Users\amart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.lru_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\amart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 59, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\backends\django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\backends\django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\backends\django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "c:\users\amart\django\django\template\backends\django.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_field': No module named 'django.utils.lru_cache'
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I have found some other users who have issues using crispy forms but are getting a different error. They were also unable to import crispy forms from the python shell but that is working for me. Even if I only add crispy forms to my installed apps without trying to apply it in my templates, I still get an error. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: Have you followed this? https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: @philipjc yes I have.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I am using django-crispy-forms1.7.2 this is the django version: (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0)

Answer (score 10):

Your version of django-crispy-forms is outdated, this has been fixed.
Update it by running:

```
pip install django-crispy-forms -U
```

`-U` makes pip upgrade your current installation to the newest.
You can find more about it by running `pip install -h`

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. I uninstalled the django version I had and used:

```
pip install Django==2.1.7
```

Thank you @YugandharChaudhari for helping me realize to change versions.